# Creating a dockerfile for a .deb file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to create a dockerfile for a debian file extension which runs on ubuntu 18.04. So far I've written this

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS ubuntu

RUN apt-get update

WORKDIR /Downloads/invisily

RUN apt-get install ./invisily.deb
```

All phases run fine except the last one. It shows this error:

```
E: Unsupported file ./invisily.deb given on commandline
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install ./invisily.deb' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I'm new to docker and cloud so any help would be appreciated thanks!

Edit:
I solved it by putting the dockerfile and the debian file in the same directory and using COPY . ./
This is what my dockerfile looks like now:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS ubuntu

RUN apt-get update

WORKDIR /invisily

COPY . ./

USER root
RUN chmod +x a.deb && \
    apt-get install a.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things,

- WORKDIR is the working directory inside of your container.
- You will need to copy the file invisily.deb from locally to your container when building your Docker image.
- You can pass multiple bash commands in the RUN field combining them with multilines.

Try something like this

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS ubuntu
WORKDIR /opt/invisily

#Drop the invisily.deb in to the same directory as your Dockerfile
#This will copy it from local to your container, inside of /opt/invisily dir
COPY invisily.deb .

RUN apt-get update && \
    chmod +x invisily.deb && \
    apt-get install invisily.deb
```

Comment: I wrote it like this including the invisily.deb file on Desktop but it still shows that: `Step 3/4 : COPY ./Desktop ./ COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat Desktop: file does not exist` This is my dockerfile: `FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS ubuntu WORKDIR /opt/invisily COPY ./Desktop ./ RUN apt-get update && \ chmod +x invisily.deb && \ apt-get install invisily.deb`

Comment: You need to pass the full path in order to copy the invisily.deb file from your local machine to the container. Try like: COPY /Desktop/invisily.deb .
Please note the dot "." at the end which will copy into the current working directory in the container.

Comment: @CaioT no, the path passed to the `COPY` command has to be _relative_ to the [build context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#extended-description)! An absolute file path won't work here since that would not be part of the build context.

Comment: You're right @acran. In this case, he would need to have a /Desktop folder in the build context with the invisily.deb file inside of it if he wants to pass ./Desktop/invisily.deb

Answer (score 0):

in your **WORKDIR** there isn't any **invisly.deb** file, so if you have it you can copy it the container like this:

```
FROM ubuntu ...
WORKDIR /Downloads/invisily
RUN apt-get update
COPY ./your invisly file path ./
RUN chmod +x ./invisily 
RUN apt-get install ./invisily.deb
```

Comment: For example my invisily file path is /Desktop/invisily.deb , I wrote it like this`COPY ./Desktop/invisily.deb ./`
But its still telling me that file doesn't exist.

Comment: if you run it like this:   COPY ./Desktop/invisily.dev ./ 
also your current directory where you are need to be "Desktop"  and command to build need to be : docker build -f ./Dockerfile .
don't forget the "."